# ASP.NET submitting the selectedvalue from a dropdownlist selection

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
             DataField="CategoryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
             DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="CategoryID">   
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </InsertItemTemplate>                            
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT Name, CategoryID FROM [tblCategory]">  
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'm trying to make a dropdownlist that submits the ID of the selected field. Only once I submit the form doesn't obtain the ID and leaves a NULL value in the database.

Comment: You haven't shown any of the markup for how you're receiving the form submission on that server side. You need that information in your question in order to have a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using this dropdownlist in your OnRowUpdating method of the grid view.

first of all, you need to give your drop down an ID, like,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" DataField="CategoryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="CategoryID"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

then, you will need to get the drop down reference, like,

```
protected void GridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList category = GridView.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlCategory") as DropDownList;

   //then, use category to get Selected Value
   //like, category.SelectedValue
   // to submit your value to the database
}
```